# android seekbar how to control thickness and thumb size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar, android-seekbar

How can i increase seekbar thickness? I would like to have this horizontal line very thick plus have thumb with much bigger circle. (holo.light)

Do I really have to create my own drabawbles? I hoped that changing only some attributes would be enough....

Comment: you have to provide custom drawables

Comment: ok thanks for help, doing even simple things in Android is like a nightmare....

Comment: why? call setRotation and see MotionEvents in onTouch and see if they differ, they should be the same, so GestureDetector should work the same

Comment: @psink - Sorry I'm not so advanced user so I don't understand what you are proposing... :(